# Can you get Windows (AD) userid in JSP (Firefox & IE)?

Tags: java, jsp

We are in the process of developing a JSP based Web application. This application needs the logged in user ID from the local PC (Windows / Ubuntu?)

This can be achieved with the help of VBScript on the but unfortunately this solution will work only on Internet Explorer

Are there any ways to get the Windows (AD) user ID in Firefox as well as IE using JSP?

My requirement is very simple. I will store a list of User ID's on my Web application (XML file preferably) and will verify against the request and if the logged in user on Windows matches my list, the user can use my application.

This is a very simple application and the user base is very minimum.

Setup: Apache Tomcat v7.x, JSP

This question may have been asked many times but I still don't see a proper way to do this

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is [Windows Authentication](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html) Tomcat has built-in support for what you want. Did not use it myself, though. Maybe someone can give you more help if the reference I gave is not enough.

Comment: looks like this is the way. Thanks. I cannot make this as answer since this is a comment. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is [Windows Authentication](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html). Tomcat has built-in support for what you want.